# Please tell me why my code timeouts while this code runs well?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

The question is 
*Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for each operation add a value to each of the array element between two given indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed, return the maximum value in your array. *

**This is my code**

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    li = [0] * n
    for query in queries:
        a, b, c = map(int, [query[0], query[1], query[2]])
        for i in range(a-1, b):
            li[i] += c
    return max(li)
```

While the code that works well is this

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    N, M = n, len(queries)
    li = [0] * n
    for i in range(M):
        a, b, k = map(int, [queries[i][0], queries[i][1], queries[i][2]])
        li[a-1] += k
        try:
            li[b] -= k
        except:
            pass

    t = li[0]
    for i in range(1, N):
        li[i] += li[i-1]
        if(li[i] > t):
            t = li[i]
    return t
```

My code gives timeout error in some testcases

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your problem description is not complete. Please tell us the data format of the input (especially `queries`), the limitations on that input, some example input, and the desired output for that input. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be especially helpful if you gave one of the testcases that causes a timeout for your code (but I know this may not be possible).

Comment: are u sure the n will always >= than the i in line second last line

Comment: there is so much static array index values are there u need to refactor your code and logic too

Comment: `for i in range(a-1, b): li[i] += c` chnage this to `for i in (a-1, b): li[i] += c` your code will work

Comment: Some sample values for `queries` would help people to answer your question.

Comment: Hello @Preet Kamal. In case you have found my answer helpful, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it, as per StackOverflow rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the first implementation may take too much time to run for some choices of `n` and `queries`, while the second implementation may be faster for the same inputs, is that the two functions have different [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity).

Consider a value of `n` of ten million (`n = 10**7`), and a `queries` list that contains ranges whose size is comparable (or equal to) `n`, such as `queries = [(1, 10**7, 42)]*10`.

## First implementation

For that input, the first implementation will execute the line (`li[i] += c`) `10* 10 ** 7 = 10**8` times, which can become noticeable (it could take a few seconds to run). Imagine that for even higher values of `n` and length of `queries`, that product will become even larger.

The number of operations, in order of magnitude, as a function of `n` and `len(queries)`, will be: `n*len(queries)`.

## Second implementation

On the contrary, the second function is optimized, so that it doesn't have a nested loop.

The operations inside the first loop:

```
for i in range(M):
    a, b, k = map(int, [queries[i][0], queries[i][1], queries[i][2]])
    li[a-1] += k
    try:
        li[b] -= k
    except:
        pass
```

are expected to run `M` times (which is `len(queries)`).

And the operations in the second loop:

```
for i in range(1, N):
    li[i] += li[i-1]
    if(li[i] > t):
        t = li[i]
```

will run `N` times (which is equal to `n`).

So the number of operations in the second function, in order of magnitude, and as a function of `n` and `len(query)`, will be: `len(query) + n`.

For example, for 10 queries and n being 10**7, the loop iterations will be `10 + 10**7 ~= 10**7`. So there is no multiplication there, and the function is expected to run faster than the first implementation.

## Measurements

You can see this for yourself. First, save the first function in a file named `solve1.py`, and the second in `solve2.py`. Then run the following in a terminal:

Running the first one:

```
time python3 -c 'from solve1 import arrayManipulation;print(arrayManipulation(10000000, [(1, 10000000, 42)]*10))'
```

Running the second one:

```
time python3 -c 'from solve2 import arrayManipulation;print(arrayManipulation(10000000, [(1, 10000000, 42)]*10))'
```

On my machine, the first one takes about 8 seconds, while the second one takes about 1.8 seconds, confirming that the second function is faster as inputs get larger.